# Find the coordinates of the point on the curve $y = \frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where the gradient is $\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: derivatives

According to the text book, the correct answer is $(4, \frac{2}{3})$

When I try to work it out, I get $x = \frac{9}{4}$

It would be tedious to put my attempt here and I'm sure this is simple for anyone who has experience with differentiation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this $$y=\frac{1}{3}x^{3/2}-x^{1/2}$$?

Comment: indeed @Dr.SonnhardGraubner !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we compute $y'(x)$ from $y = \frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} - x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ we get: $y'(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}} -\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

We know that $y'(x) = \frac{3}{4}$, thus $\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}} -\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3}{4} \Leftrightarrow x=4$.

And $y(4)=\frac{2}{3}$,
so the answer is indeed: $(4, \frac{2}{3})$.

Edit (answer):

$$\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}} -\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3}{4} \Leftrightarrow x=4$$.

Let $u = x^{\frac{1}{2}}$, then:

$$u -\frac{1}{u} =\frac{3}{2}$$
$$u^2 -\frac{3}{2}u -1 =0$$
$$(u-2)(u+\frac{1}{2})=0$$

Thus: $u=2\lor u=-\frac{1}{2}$

$\Rightarrow x=u^2=4$

Comment: could you please explain how you worked out the second line? I got to this stage but kept making didn't manage to get x = 4, so there's something missing in my logic

Comment: I will edit my answer to explain how I did it.

Comment: I hope the answer helped

Comment: Yes it did, thanks a lot. I guess abstracting that common term makes the calculation a lot simpler. Something to keep in mind for the future. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, accept the answer to close this question for the forum. So that people can help otters :)

Comment: @Jay M And indeed u-substitution is quite useful!

Comment: sorry I didn't realise I could press the tick! I was trying to upvote but needed 5 more points to able to do that.

Comment: Upvote won't hurt anyway ;)